# Присвоить элементу массива значение

Tags: c++, сортировка

Мне нужно базу отсортировать с помощью merge sort по именам.
Я передаю массив с базой
Ошибка возникает на моменте присваивания значению массива элемента "no suitable conversation function from "database" to "database*" exists" --- "record[k] = L[i];"
Как его присвоить?

```
struct database 
{
    char name[32] = {0};
    unsigned short int number;
    char date[8] = {0};
    char lawyer[22] = {0};
} * stacks;
void merge(database *record[], int first, int mid, int last)
{
    database *L = new database[mid - first + 1];
    database *R = new database[last - mid];

    for (int i = 0; i < (mid - first + 1); i++)
    {
        L[i] = *(record[first + i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < (last - mid); j++)
    {
        R[j] = *(record[mid + j + 1]);
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = first;
    for (; (i < (mid - first + 1)) && (j < (last - mid)); k++)
    {
        if (L[i].name[i] <= R[j].name[j])
        {
            record[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            record[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (; i < (mid - first + 1); i++, k++)
    {
        record[k] = L[i];
    }
    for (; j < (last - mid); j++, k++)
    {
        record[k] = R[j];
    }
}

void mergeSort(database *record[], int first, int mid, int last)
{

    if (first < last)
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        mergeSort(record, first, mid);
        mergeSort(record, mid + 1, last);
        merge(record, first, mid, last);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что `record` у вас объявлен как массив указателей, а `L` как динамический массив. Измените строку на `*record[k] = L[i];` - заведется.